# Two types of Chebyshev centers

Tags: metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces

There are two types of definitions for Chebyshev centers,  from wikipedia, it says the Chebyshev center of a bounded set Q having non-empty interior is the center of the minimal-radius ball enclosing the entire set Q, or alternatively the center of largest inscribed ball of Q. I think there should be some kind of duality between them, are there some simple relations between the two centers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit tricky to formulate a duality between them, since the largest inscribed ball is not always unique (e.g. a rectangle in the plane), whereas the smallest enveloping ball is always unique (in a reflexive space, including all finite-dimensional spaces).

However, there is something we can do, but first let's formulate the problem. Let $X$ be a real Hilbert Space (in finite dimensions, $\mathbb{R}^n$ with inner product $\langle x, y \rangle := x.y$; the dot product). Let $\iota_{x, r}$ be the operation of inversion in the sphere $S_X[x; r] := \lbrace y \in X : \|y - x\| = r \rbrace$. For a subset $\emptyset \neq Q \subseteq X$, we'll denote by $c(Q)$ the centre of the ball of minimal radius that envelopes $Q$ (where $Q$ is bounded), and denote by $C(Q)$ the set of centres of balls of maximal radius that are contained in $Q$. Furthermore, we denote $r(Q)$ and $R(Q)$ to be the respective radii of these balls.

Let us consider the case where the interior of $Q$ is non-empty and $C(Q) \neq \emptyset$ (otherwise the problem becomes somewhat silly). So, in particular, $R(Q) > 0$. Let $y \in C(Q)$, consider the image of the set $X \setminus Q$ under the operation $\iota_{y, R(Q)}$, and call it $A_y$. Then $y = c(A_y)$.

How does this work? Proving it requires some tedious algebra, but can be understood well enough with some geometry. When in an inner product space (or indeed, a Hilbert space), the operation $\iota_{x, r}$ preserves "generalised spheres", meaning spheres and hyperplanes. So, every sphere maps to a sphere or hyperplane (and the same for hyperplanes). A sphere will only map to a hyperplane if the sphere goes through $x$, the centre of the sphere in which you are inverting. Note also that $\iota_{x,r}$ is an involution, meaning that $\iota_{x, r}^2 = I$.

Moreover, if you map a ball containing $x$ in its interior under $\iota_{x, r}$, then the image will be the (unbounded) complement of another ball. If the ball does not contain $x$ in its interior, then it will map to another ball (not of the same centre). If $x$ is on the sphere of the ball, then the ball maps to a half-space.

Here's something to note about $A_y$: it is contained in $B[y; R(Q)]$. This is because we inverted in the sphere the set $X \setminus Q$, which was entirely contained outside the sphere, so the resulting set $A_y$ lies in the ball. From this, we conclude that $r(A_y) \le R(Q)$.

Another fact about $A_y$ is that, given any ball $B$ containing $A_y$, we must have $y \in \operatorname{int}(B)$. This can be deduced by the geometric facts above. It therefore follows that any ball containing $A_y$ will map to the complement of a ball, where the ball is contained in $Q$. It takes some formulae to prove formally, but the smaller the ball containing $A_y$, the larger the ball inside $Q$. Where they achieve their common optimisation is at $y$, with radius $R(Q)$.

So, in conclusion, we can take any Chebyshev centre (of one type) $y \in C(Q)$, perform an involution on the set (mapping under an inversion, then taking the complement) to recover a set $A_y$ whose (unique) Chebyshev centre (of the other type) is also $y$. It's not much of a duality, but it's something.

Aside: These techniques were used to make some of the most significant progress on the Chebyshev conjecture, and originally attributed to F. A. Ficken. Using these techniques, a non-convex Chevyshev set (a set for which each point has a unique closest point in the set) could be turned into a uniquely remotal set (a set for which each point has a unique furthest point in the set).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a nice property to know.